# how to upgrade httpcore-nio plugin of wso2 api manager

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am testing wso2 api manager 4.0.0. Periodically I am receiving an alert of high cpu utilization. After analyzing the thread usage I found out that SSLIOSession class was the root cause of the problem. Googling the problem led me to this [issue](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio/pull/38).

After the HTTPS response is written back to the client, the server tries to close the connection and the SSLIOSession. Prior to JDK 8 261 versions (& Prior to Oracle JDK 11.0.2), after SSLIOSession closes the outBound connection, the Handshake status is returned as NEED_UNWRAP. When such status is returned, we set the new event Mask as Read EventMask. In the new JDK versions it is returned as NOT_HANDSHAKING. In such cases, the SSLSession is not getting closed properly, and the server is constantly trying to close the connection which causes the CPU spike.

That's why I am trying to upgrade httpcore-nio plugin from version 4.4.14 to 4.4.16. so that it works as expected. What I have done so far was build and put the jar file with new version (4.4.16) into the patch folder. But when I start the api manager it's stuck.

Any navigation or tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended. The recommended approach is to migrate to the latest version.

But if you still want to patch it, checkout the `4.4.14` tag, then apply the [fix](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio/pull/38/files), then build the source and apply it as a patch.

Comment: I searched for the appropriate tag in the repository https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio/tags but could not find the tag with 4.4.14. Where I can find it?

Comment: @Frank Interesting. Seems they have not tagged the source. Probably you will have to reset to this commit and build from there. https://github.com/wso2/wso2-httpcore-nio/blob/49da50b1b2947f8b9613b9f691743a5fb6228eda/pom.xml#L36
Make sure this is the latest commit on that version. Or you can get a later tag and change the pom version to 4.4.14.